# jQuery Mobile hash links getting cached after first clicked link until shift+f5

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, hash

I have a website that uses jQuery Mobile library, and there are several links that look like the following:

```
<a href="#news?A">News for A zipcode</a>
<a href="#news?B">News for B</a>
<a href="#news?C">News for C</a>
```

Whatever link is clicked on first seems to get cached by the browser for all subsequent links that have the same `#news` prefix.  Example...

1. User clicks on 2nd link to `#news?B`, the browser correctly goes to `#news?B`
2. User clicks back button, is taken back home
3. User clicks on 1st link to `#news?A`, the browser INcorrectly goes to `#news?B` (cached from step 1?)

If I shift-f5 again, whatever link I click on after that becomes the "cached" link from that point forward.  Any ideas?  I've tested this both on my phone, and in Chrome with a User Agent switcher (to fake my browser out to think it's a mobile device).

**Edit** - I think I've found the answer here, http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html. Will test and verify before updating this s.o. question.

Comment: Could you post a little more code?

Comment: You can see a working example here - http://seeitornot.co. If you switch your user agent to mobile, and click showtimes tab, then specify a location, if you choose different theaters, you'll always see the first theater that you picked.

Comment: What's handling the templates? jQuery? BTW I like this site

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com is the library I'm using. and, thanks! feel free to click the Facebook "Like" in the desktop version ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like this

```
<a href="#news_A">News for A zipcode</a>
<a href="#news_B">News for B</a>
<a href="#news_C">News for C</a>
```

And also change the code to use `_` in place of `?` if you are accessing it elsewhere

Also you can use safari to test it for iPhone or iPad more precisely than chrome's UA switcher. Chrome is good for Android testing though.
You have to go preferences and enable developer menu. In developer menu you will have options to switch user agent.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, if the hash link has "#news" as the prefix, jquery mobile knows to show the `<div data-role="page" id="news">...</div>` element. If I change it to `#news_A`, jquery mobile will try and find the div with id of `news_A`, which does not exist. I might try links like `#news?zip=A` instead of `#news?A`, so the browser recognizes that key/value pairing in the query string, and not to cache it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, hash.location is not updating to the clicked/tapped link (Theater).

I used the data-url attribute to pull the correct information:

Example:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', function (e, o) {
    var dataURL = $('#theater').attr('data-url'); // Use this for the Theater Location as hash is not updating
    var hash = location.hash;
    var action = hash.split('?')[0]; // #whatshot, #showtimes, #zip?{zip}, #theater?{zip},{theaterId}
    var args = dataURL.split('?')[1].split(',');
    var zip = args[0];
    var theaterId = args[1];

    // load theater movies
    codejkjk.movies.Api.GetTheaterMovies(codejkjk.movies.Mobile.Currents.ShowtimeDay(), codejkjk.movies.Mobile.Currents.ZipCode(), theaterId, function (theater) {
        codejkjk.movies.Mobile.Controls.CurrentTheater().html(theater.name);
        codejkjk.movies.Mobile.Controls.TheaterMovieList().html(
            codejkjk.movies.Mobile.Controls.TheaterMovieTemplate().render(theater)
        ).show().listview('refresh'); //.trigger('create');

        // set theaterMovieBackUrl
        theaterMovieBackUrl = hash; // set back url to current url

        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
});
```

I used this function in the Chrome console

Comment: for the first approach, I only have 1 `<div data-role="page" id="news">...</div>` element on the page, and the contents of it depend on what's in the query string (`#news?A` shows news that are from "A" zipcode). so, I can't really do that b/c that would mean having a separate page element for each and every zipcode. I might try the data-dom-cache="false" on that 1 page, see if that does it.

Comment: tried data-dom-cache on my single <div data-role="page" id="news">...</div>, and the issue persists. ugh. it's weird because the url has `#news?A`, but if I inspect element on the single page div, it has `data-url="news?B"` how can I tell jquery mobile to stop messing with my links?